# How we can loop over SQL Column with specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Explanations:

1. In 1st picture data we have.
2. In the 2nd picture report we want to generate using SQL.
3. In the last we have added table and data script

[image: We have SQL Data in this format.]

[image: We want Report Like this]

4. Column Calculation = 2(Yes)/3(Total Column Contain Yes/NO) *100

Sample data:

```
    CREATE TABLE tableName 
(
    SNo INT,
    UserName    varchar(50),
    CL1 varchar(10),
    CL2 varchar(10),
    CL3 varchar(10),
    CL4 varchar(10),
    CL5 varchar(10),
    CL6 varchar(10),
    CL7 varchar(10),
    CL8 varchar(10),
    DateOfSubmit     VARCHAR(300)
);

INSERT INTO tableName (SNo,UserName,CL1,CL2,CL3,CL4,CL5,CL6,CL7,CL8,DateOfSubmit)
VALUES
    ('1', 'U1', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'Friday, January 1, 2021'),
    ('2', 'U1', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'Saturday, January 2, 2021'),
    ('3', 'U1', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'Sunday, January 3, 2021');
```

Comment: Please show your attempt and describe what is the issue with it. Also post sample data and desired output [**in text format**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Comment: Looks like you need to pivot then unpivot, but it's pretty unclear.

Comment: Do you need additional columns for another month(s)?

Comment: @Zhorov Yes! We need additional columns for another month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpivot the `CL` values first and then implement a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([YearMonth]), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [YearMonth])
FROM (
   SELECT CONVERT(
             varchar(6), 
             CONVERT(date, STUFF(DateOfSubmit, 1 , CHARINDEX(', ', DateOfSubmit), ''), 107), 
             112
          ) AS [YearMonth]
   FROM tableName
   UNION
   SELECT NULL
   WHERE 1 = 0
) t

SELECT @stmt = 
   N'SELECT UserName, C_Name,  ' + @cols +
   N'FROM ( ' +
      N'SELECT ' + 
         N't.UserName, ' +
         N'CONVERT(varchar(6), CONVERT(date, STUFF(t.DateOfSubmit, 1 , CHARINDEX('', '', t.DateOfSubmit), ''''), 107), 112) AS [YearMonth], ' +
         N'a.C_Name, ' +
         N'a.CL ' +
      N'FROM tableName t ' +
      N'CROSS APPLY (VALUES ' + 
         N'(''CL1'', CASE WHEN t.CL1 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END), ' +
         N'(''CL2'', CASE WHEN t.CL2 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END), ' +
         N'(''CL3'', CASE WHEN t.CL3 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END), ' +
         N'(''CL4'', CASE WHEN t.CL4 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END), ' +
         N'(''CL5'', CASE WHEN t.CL5 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END), ' +
         N'(''CL6'', CASE WHEN t.CL6 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END), ' +
         N'(''CL7'', CASE WHEN t.CL7 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END), ' +
         N'(''CL8'', CASE WHEN t.CL8 = ''YES'' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) ' +
      N') a (C_Name, CL) ' +
   N') x ' +
   N'PIVOT ( ' +
      N'AVG(CL)' +
      N'FOR [YearMonth] IN (' + @cols + ') ' +
   N') p'

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt
```

Results:

```
UserName C_Name 202101
--------------------------
U1       CL1    66.666666
U1       CL2    100.000000
U1       CL3    100.000000
U1       CL4    33.333333
U1       CL5    100.000000
U1       CL6    100.000000
U1       CL7    100.000000
U1       CL8    100.000000
```

Comment: Hi @Zhorov what we do when I have more than one month

Comment: @PradeepVaishya, you need to implement a dynamic `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple `UNPIVOT` query.

```
select
  username,
  c_name,
  avg(case when yes_or_no = 'YES' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as ratio
from tablename
unpivot (yes_or_no FOR c_name IN (CL1,CL2,CL3,CL4,CL5,CL6,CL7,CL8)) unpvt
group by username, c_name
order by username, c_name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a3fb6ebb652ca34beca1792e98cf900